# next-auth issues: Unresolved variable FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET & Missing import statement process

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to create a web where users can sign in using facebook accounts. I have installed next-auth and got the id and client id & secret, but the file [...nextauth.js] always report errors:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook"


export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        // ...add more providers here
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],

});
```

Missing import statement for "process"
and
Unresolved variable FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID
and
Unresolved variable FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET

There shouldn't have been errors reported as the functions or classes (process and FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID...) should be included in next-auth library. According to the tutorial I am shadow copying, there are no differences between the video content and what I have coded either. Is it probabily because the next-auth version I am using is the newest one?